# How to convert the positions of connected joints to relative delta rotations

Tags: c++, quaternions

I'm currently implementing a C++ solution to track motion of multiple objects. In that I have tracked points of those objects in a frame sequences such that multiple points in each frame. As a result of that I have x, y, z coordinates of those points of the entire frame sequence. By studying an already generated model I understood it consists of a joints system which move relative to each other. Every joint has a parent and their movements are written relative to its parent in Quaternion format. Therefore, I want to convert my x,y,z coordinates, which are in 3D space relative to same origin, to quaternion format which are written as relative to its parent. I can then use the quaternions to animate them.

I don't understand how to calculate the angle that it requires. Can you please provide me a sample code (in c++) or any useful resources to overcome this problem.

Comment: Do you understand the geometry of the problem? What exactly are you stuck with?

Comment: related, not dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508370/quaternion-libraries-in-c-c

Comment: Do you know if the only transformation present is the rotation? Can the points have different coordinates due to translation(or any other transformation) also?

Comment: This is not really a C++ question, unless you have figured out the maths and need help with the implementation, in which case you should tell us what you have tried.

Comment: At least if memory serves, converting a point to a quaternion means your quaternion will be [x, y, z, 0].

Comment: maybe this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715776/using-quaternions-for-opengl-rotations?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

So we have a system of connected joints and we want to find out the the relative delta rotation of the joints from one frame to another. I'll call the relative rotation the **local rotation** since the "relative rotation" on it's own doesn't tell us what it's relative to. (Is it relative to an object, to the center of the universe, etc?)

#### Assumptions

I'm going to assume a tree structure of joints so that each joint only has one parent and we only have one root joint (without parents). If you have several parents per joint you should be able to use the same solution, but you'll then each joint will one relative rotation per parent and you need to do the calcualtion once for each parent. If you have several joints without parents then each one can be thought of as a root in it's own tree made up of the connected joints.

I'll assume you have a quaternion math library that can; create from an axis and an angle, set to identity, inverse, and accumulate quaternions. If you don't you should find all the info you need to implement them from Wikipedia or Google.

#### Calulating the rotations

The code below first calculates the local rotations of the joint for the start and the end of the frame. It does this calculation using two vector; the vector from it's parent and the vector from the grandparent to the parent. Then in order to calculate the delta rotation it uses the inverted start rotation to "remove" the start rotation from the end rotation by applying it's inverse rotation. So we end up with the local delta rotation for that frame.

For the first two levels of the joint hierarchy we have special cases which we can solve directly.

#### Pseudocode

The out parameter is a multidimensional array named *result*. 
NB: *startPosition, endPosition, parentStartPosition, parentEndPosition, grandParentStartPosition, grandParentStartPosition* all have to be updated for each iteration of the loops. That update is **not** shown in order to focus on the core of the problem.

```
for each frame {
  for each joint {

    if no parent {
      // no parent means no local rotation
      result[joint,frame] = identityQuaternion
    } 
    else {
      startLink = startPosition - parentStartPosition
      endLink = endPosition - parentEndPosition

      if no grandParent {
        // no grand parent - we can calculate the local rotation directly
        result[joint,frame] = QuaternionFromVectors( startLink, endLink )
      } 
      else {
        parentStartLink = parentStartPosition - grandParentStartPosition
        parentEndLink = parentEndPosition - grandParentEndPosition

        // calculate the local rotations 
        // = the difference in rotation between parent link and child link
        startRotation = QuaternionFromVectors( parentStartLink, startLink )
        endRotation = QuaternionFromVectors( parentEndLink, endLink )

        // calculate the delta local rotation
        // = the difference between start and end local rotations
        invertedStartRotation = Inverse( startRotation )
        deltaRotation = invertedStartRotation.Rotate( endRotation )
        result[joint,frame] = deltaRotation 
      }
    }
  }
}

QuaternionFromVectors( fromVector, toVector ) 
{
  axis = Normalize( fromVector.Cross( toVector ) )
  angle = Acos( fromVector.Dot( toVector ) )
  return Quaternion( axis, angle )
}
```

#### C++ implementation

Below is an untested recursive implementation in C++. For each frame we start at the root of our *JointData* tree and then traverse the tree by recursivly calling the *JointData::calculateRotations()* function.

In order to make the code easier to read I have an accessor from the joint tree nodes *JointData* to the *FrameData*. You probably don't want to have such a direct dependency in your implementation.

```
// Frame data holds the individual frame data for a joint
struct FrameData
{
    Vector3 m_positionStart;
    Vector3 m_positionEnd;

    // this is our unknown
    Quaternion m_localDeltaRotation;
}

class JointData
{
public:
    ...
    JointData *getChild( int index );
    int getNumberOfChildren();

    FrameData *getFrame( int frameIndex );

    void calculateDeltaRotation( int frameIndex, JointData *parent = NULL, 
                                 Vector3& parentV1 = Vector3(0), 
                                 Vector3& parentV2 = Vector3(0) );
    ...
}

void JointData::calculateDeltaRotation( int frameIndex, JointData *parent, 
                                        Vector3& parentV1, Vector3& parentV2 )
{
    FrameData *frameData = getFrame( frameIndex );

    if( !parent ) 
    {
        // this is the root, it has no local rotation
        frameData->m_localDeltaRotation.setIdentity();
        return;
    }

    FrameData *parentFrameData = parent->getFrame( frameIndex );

    // calculate the vector from our parent
    // for the start (v1) and the end (v2) of the frame
    Vector3 v1 = frameData->m_positionStart - parentFrameData->m_positionStart;
    Vector3 v2 = frameData->m_positionEnd - parentFrameData->m_positionEnd;

    if( !getParent()->getParent() )
    {
        // child of the root is a special case, 
        // we can calculate it's rotation directly          
        frameData->m_localDeltaRotation = calculateQuaternion( v1, v2 );
    }
    else
    {
        // calculate start and end rotations
        // apply inverse start rotation to end rotation 
        Quaternion startRotation = calculateQuaternion( parentV1, v1 );
        Quaternion endRotation = calculateQuaternion( parentV2, v2 );       
        Quaternion invStartRot = startRotation.inverse();

        frameData->m_localDeltaRotation = invStartRot.rotate( endRotation );
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < getNumberOfChildren(); ++i )
    {
        getChild( i )->calculateRotations( frameIndex, this, v1, v2 );
    }
}

// helper function to calulate a quaternion from two vector
Quaternion calculateQuaternion( Vector3& fromVector, Vector3& toVector )
{
    float angle = acos( fromVector.dot( toVector ) );
    Vector3 axis = fromVector.cross( toVector );
    axis.normalize();
    return Quaternion( axis, angle );   
}
```

The code is written for readability and not to be optimal.

Comment: Thank you for response. Let me again explain my question. I have tracked x,y,z coordinates of points from a frame sequence successfully. I want to map those coordinates with an object model. By studying an already generated model I understood it consists of a joints system which move relative to each other. Every joint has a parent and their movements are written relative to its parent in Quaternion format. Therefore, I want to convert my x,y,z coordinates which are in 3D space relative to same origin to quaternion format which are written as relative to its parent.

Comment: Ok, that is a bit easier to solve. :) I have rewritten my answer now that I understand your question better. You might want to edit the original question and add your explanation to it.

Comment: Thanks Jens for the response. But my domain knowledge about model animation is bit low. So I couldn't understand the code you have posted. So it would be great if you can give me a little bit more explanation of the code. Actually I need your local rotation as relative to the original model's quaternions. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, let me know which parts you don't understand and I'll try to clarify. This code will give you only the change in the local rotations for each frame, so they are relative to the original quaternions (the start rotation if you will). I think that is what you want?

Comment: What is the meaning of " Vector3 v1 = frameData->m_positionStart - parentFrameData->m_positionStart;
    Vector3 v2 = frameData->m_positionEnd - parentFrameData->m_positionEnd;" because it is some what unclear to me. Also why do you calculate a inverse in "Quaternion invStartRot = startRotation.inverse();". I don't understand the meaning of storing data about each node's children. If you can give me a pseudo code kind of thing it will be grate. Thank you.

Comment: I added some clarifications in the text and a comment regarding v1 and v2. v1 and v2 are vectors from our parents. Think of them as the link between the parent joint and the child joint. We can use that link and parent's link to the grandparent to create the current rotation of the joint.

Comment: I explain the inverse in the text. It's used to create the delta rotation from the end rotation. Think of it as removing the start rotation from then end rotation. We are left with only the rotation from the start to the end.

Comment: There's no need to store the children if you don't want to. I just used a tree since it was an easy way to traverse the joints. You can use some other data structure.

Comment: I agree that the C++ code was not really easy to read. I've therefore added some pseudocode to the answer that focuses more on the core of the problem.

Comment: Thank You Jens. I have implemented the code. But the Problem is there is a discrepancy error between our data and the model data. (There is a difference between the length of the bone system of the model and our data). I checked that using rotation and orientation of model data and we got the correct output. Therefore I got the conclusion that my mapping is absolutely correct.

Comment: Could you clarify this last comment a bit. Did the algorithm not work for you or is there an error in the sampled data? Did you get everything to work in the end using this algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

```
Point3d Controller::calRelativeToParent(int parentID,Point3d point,int frameID){
if(parentID == 0){
    QUATERNION temp = calChangeAxis(-1,parentID,frameID);
    return getVect(multiplyTwoQuats(multiplyTwoQuats(temp,getQuat(point)),getConj(temp)));
}else{
    Point3d ref = calRelativeToParent(originalRelativePointMap[parentID].parentID,point,frameID);
    QUATERNION temp = calChangeAxis(originalRelativePointMap[parentID].parentID,parentID,frameID);  
    return getVect(multiplyTwoQuats(multiplyTwoQuats(temp,getQuat(ref)),getConj(temp)));
}}
QUATERNION Controller::calChangeAxis(int parentID,int qtcId,int frameID){ //currentid = id of the position of the orientation to be changed
if(parentID == -1){
    QUATERNION out = multiplyTwoQuats(quatOrigin.toChange,originalRelativePointMap[qtcId].orientation);
    return out;
}
else{
    //QUATERNION temp = calChangeAxis(originalRelativePointMap[parentID].parentID,qtcId,frameID);
    //return multiplyTwoQuats(finalQuatMap[frameID][parentID].toChange,temp);
    return multiplyTwoQuats(finalQuatMap[frameID][parentID].toChange,originalRelativePointMap[qtcId].orientation);  
}}
```

This is the algorithm I have used. I first calculated the relative vector of each frame wrt to it's parent. Here parent ID of root is 0. Then I calculated the relative vector in the model for each joint. This is called recursively.