# C + OpenGL quaternions

Tags: c, opengl, quaternions

A quaternion is a number of the form:

```
a + bi + cj + dk
```

Right? Good, but...

1. How do I interpret this number in C language?
2. If for example I want to rotate a cube What multiplied by the quaternion? A vector?

Comment: To represent a quarternion, you either need a struct with 4 members, or a length-4 array.  As for the rest of your questions, that's essentially maths, and so is off-topic for SO...

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508370/quaternion-libraries-in-c-c?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your first question, I think you mean "how do I represent", not "interpret".

The simplest way is to use a `struct`:

```
typedef struct quaternion_t {
  double x,y,z,w;
} quaternion_t;
```

Note that a usual practice, as used above,  is also to use x, y, z, and w for the component names (but your naming is perfectly acceptable, as long as you know which one is which). The use of double or single precision floats for components depends on your needs: accuracy or space.

Simple operations are then easy to implement:

```
void conjugate(quaternion_t *q){
    q->x = -q->x;
    q->y = -q->y;
    q->z = -q->z;
}

double product(quaternion_t *q1, quaternion_t *q2){
    return q1->x * q2->x + q1->y * q2->y + q1->z * q2->z + q1->w * q2->w;
}

double norm(quaternion_t *q){
    double p = product(q,q);
    return sqrt(p);
}

// etc
```

For your second question, I suggest that you look for a good tutorial on that topic. Meanwhile, the wikipedia pages:

- [Quaternion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion)
- [Quaternions and spatial rotation](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation)

provide a good introduction.

Comment: I'd go with double, unless size is an issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great help friend ;-)

Comment: no problem, what's the point of asking if the answer is known already.

Answer (score 4):

Whether you code this in C or C++, the math will be exactly the same.

See here for some details:

[quaternion libraries in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508370/quaternion-libraries-in-c-c)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion
http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/docu/classirr_1_1core_1_1quaternion.html
https://irrlicht.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/irrlicht/trunk/include/quaternion.h